# `\endgroup` error with {dinbrief} and XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, compilation-error, grouping, dinbrief

First, let's consider this minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{dinbrief}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}
test
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

This document compiles sortof fine with PDFlatex and LuaLatex, but XeLatex, I'm getting this error:

```
*** dinbrief: Running in LaTeX 2e mode!
*** dinbrief: NFSS 2!
Document Class: dinbrief 2000/03/02 LaTeX2e class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/dinbrief/dinbrief.cfg))
! Extra \endgroup.
\document ->\endgroup 
                      \ifka@db@ltxtwoe \ifx \@unusedoptionlist \@empty \else...
l.3 \begin{document}
```

I could narrow down the problem to be with dinbrief.sty, but I'm not sure where to go from here. On one hand I'd like to keep using dinbrief for my letters, but I'm also considering moving on to a different package if it won't work correctly with XeLatex, etc.

I'm unsure whether it is me that's having an error, or if it's the package / documentclass that's the problem. I remember a couple years ago, it was working fine, but apparently that ain't so anymore.

Comment: it's not specifically xelatex, you would see the same with pdflatex or lualatex, see the refenced answer for a workaround

Comment: do not use dinbrief for new documents. The work-around will not resolve all problems, only avoid the error.

Comment: beside this: it shouldn't error in a current LaTeX, so check if your formats are actually up-to-date.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer what else should I use instead? gbrief2?

Comment: no idea, I'm using some old home made sty. But if I had to choose something I would look for something that looks new and maintained and probably start with the scrletter package, or perhaps check the ntgclasses.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer OK, I guess I'll check {scrlttr2} if it suits me. KOMA classes still look like they're maintained, etc. Thanks for the suggestions!